# How to simulate a short key press

Tags: dfplayer

I have a MP3player (DFPlayer Mini module). This module has a pin which allows to start next track with a short pull to GND. I want to make it work without a physical button. I believe there is way to achieve this with a small circuitry.

How to do this, without an Arduino or another microcontroller?

PS. Track must be started right after powering up with 5V power supply.

Comment: It would help if you provided more information: pictures of the unit, along with voltages and current flows with the switch open and closed.  You also haven't been clear about what trigger you want to use.  Are you simply looking for it to start at power up?

Answer (score 1):

Circuit below generate a short pull to Gnd right after power on.
The time of pull is given by R1R2C1 time constant (aproximatelly).
With values in schematic it is about 200ms.
To change this time change the C1.
R3 just discharges the C1 after power supply is off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2PCU5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Note: If the Player needs a little delay between power-on and pin pulling just add another cap (10u) between BE of transistor.*

Comment: I might add a discharge diode from the bottom of C1 (cathode) to ground (anode) rather than force a slower discharge when power goes off.